# How to expose a particular port in Amazon Desktop workspace to connect through public IP from external world

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-workspaces

I recently created a Widnows 10 Workspace and install one of my app utility, which listen a particular port [let's assume 42474]. How can I access this port from external world through web or any other way. 
What I did so far is, I followed some instructions from AWS and created an Elastic IP which I assigned to VPC. I also created access control rules and security group but still the port is not accessible from external. 
I'm checking port availability from https://portchecker.co/check.

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong over there.

Comment: Did you  open the port in security group for all the IP addresses?

Comment: Yes I opened it for all the IP Address, Global range

Comment: Are you able to remote login to the machine?

Comment: I'm able to access it through Amazon Workspace client

Comment: Open the port in the security group to 0.0.0.0:0 and access through the port. The port open checker is not good to check the port opened, because it only works with any app or server is running on that port. If there is nothing running, then the port is marked as closed even if the security group is allowed.

Comment: I checked that part Lamanus, I just give the example of that port checker website. Although I tried several other port checker.  on the second hand I already applied that global ip to the security range and yes my port is opened and a service is running on that. it is a listening port.